# Isn't the Java LinkedList API redundant?

Tags: java, api, collections, linked-list

Don't the methods `add`, `addLast`, `offer` and `offerLast` in the Java LinkedList class perform the same thing? If so, why does the API design trade off brevity for redundancy?

Comment: Look at the interfaces [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) implements. To be that kind of polymorphic, it has to implement those methods.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `LinkedList` class implements the interfaces `List` and `Deque`. So the class needs to implement those four methods even though, you're right, they do quite the same.

By the way, the `LinkedList` is not the API. If you use an interface, like

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

for example, then you won't see the methods `addLast`, `offer` and `offerLast`.

Comment: Absolutely, List<T> is an interface that did not have methods `addLast`, `offer` and `offerLast` :).